# Azure Batch error : "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Tags: javascript, nodes, azure-batch

I'm new to Azure Batch and I'm stuck on an error that I can't seem to solve.
I followed this tutorial https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/JavaScript to test Azure Batch but the service is not running and I have this error when I look in the "preparation tasks" menu : "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

The problem occurs when the command "sudo sh startup_prereq.sh > startup.log" of the sample.js file is executed.
According to the different comments on internet, it will be necessary to provide a user and password to pass it but I don't know how to do it.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding this in sample.js file:

```
userIdentity: {
                autoUser: {
                    elevationLevel: "admin",
                    scope: "pool"
                }
              }
```

[image]

And the same sequence, I added it in the createTasks part:
[image]

I have successfully installed the packages as shown in this file workitems/processcsvjob/job-1/installprereq/stdout.txt which does not point to any errors.